# When selecting input don't minimize window - pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, qt

I am making a plugin and I have a window in which you have to select an input file. There is a pushButton and lineEdit. I am typing a path and when clicking OK button to go back to window it minimalize. How can I avoid it?

Here is my code:

```
def select_input_file(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.iface.mainWindow(), "Choose input file ", os.getcwd(), "*.qml")
        self.d.lineEdit.setText(filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in that way:

```
def select_input_file(self):
    self.d.lineEdit.setText(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Choose input file ", os.getcwd(), "*.qml"))
```

Without this iface as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your method with this.
You only need change self.iface.mainWindow() for self.

```
def select_input_file(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Choose input file ", os.getcwd(), "*.qml")
    if fileName=="":
        return
    self.d.lineEdit.setText(filename)       
    return
```

The dialog closed when you click ok button.

Comment: Please try to include some explanation with your answer.  While it may be correct and make sense to you, it may not be clear to the asker (or others looking for the same solution) where and how to use your code, and maybe why.

Comment: Edit my answer with bit explanation